# php curl line breaks send lf instead of crlf

Tags: php, curl

I am having trouble with curl in php. My application uses a header to authenticate the client and when I send a request with curl from another server I got error.

Analyzing what I debug with Charles a client of my application in android send headers line breaks as LF, but curl sent it as CRLF, is there a way to change that?

Answer (score 0):

Dont understand your question 100%, but try use curl library for debugging, or download google chrome extension to view your requests.

Another good practice is have print messages to see exactly where you went wrong

```
$data = array(
          // for item fields array is not nessary and nf_ingredient_statement
            "fields" => "your fields",
           "appId" => "appID",
           "appKey"=> "appKey"
          );

         $getInput= "query";

          $d_string = http_build_query($data);  
          $url='https://website.com/search/'. rawurlencode($getInput)."?".$d_string;
          $d_string = http_build_query($data);  


        $ch=curl_init();                                                             
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        //print_r($result);
        $result_arr = json_decode($result, true);
       //print_r($result_arr); 
       return $result_arr;
```